# Trying to save strings in Azure blob storage with C#, getting strange errors

Tags: c#, azure

I'm making an API call to a website, getting back some data and trying to save it as a blob in Azure blob storage.

I'm getting strange exceptions in my debug output window, but they're not coming up on in my try/catch exception handling (I've got a breakpoint set there as well.) The data is not saving in Azure.

Here is my code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("connectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("data");
                container.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{measurementString}.json");
await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(resultContent);
```

With a breakpoint, I can see the container is created.

And I get this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`
```

My .NET version is 4.5.2, and my package versions are:

```
Environment: <packages> <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net452" /> <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" /> <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.3" targetFramework="net452" /> </packages>
```

When I put a breakpoint on await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(resultContent);, it never comes up!

EDIT: I changed the blob name string .ToLower() and it seemse to be working fine now. I guess that was it!

Comment: ...and what's in the exception? Message, details..?

Comment: That's the thing-I can only see the exceptions in the debug output window on the bottom. No details. Any idea how I can get them?

Comment: As a very simple method, just put a try catch block around your code and put a breakpoint in the catch block :)

Comment: I did exactly that-they're not showing up there.

Comment: Please tell us about your environment like what's SDK version, .Net version etc. Also tell us if you put a breakpoint at `await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(resultContent);`, what's the value you see for `blockblob` variable?

Comment: Environment:
`<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
 <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>`

When I put a breakpoint on `await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(resultContent);`, it never comes up!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the previous line, `CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{measurementString}.json");`-when I put a breakpoint there, I can see that the container is created fine, and the measurementString.json shows up, but blockBlob is blank.

Comment: What's the target .Net version?

Comment: According to App.config and the packages.config, 4.5.2

Comment: Interesting! I just tried and it worked fine for me. What's the value for `measurementString` variable?

Comment: Can you please take all these details being placed in comments, and *edit your question*? This is becoming very difficult to read/follow. Details like these shouldn't be placed in comments.

Comment: Yes, done, thanks David.

Comment: That's a bit bizarre, blob names are not constrained to all lowercase. What's the name of that blob?

Comment: Ok, great that you solved it. Please post a proper answer to close this out (vs editing the question to contain an answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the blob name string .ToLower() and it seemse to be working fine now. I guess that was it!